# Get label name of top running activity in the stack Android

Tags: android

I am using following line of code to get the package name of top running application in Android

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

What I want is the label name of top running activity in the stack, like if facebook is running on the top , I should get *"facebook"* as label name of the application

Comment: so what out put you are currently get

Comment: like if facebook is running on top of the stack , using topA

Comment: like if facebook is running as top activity , currently what i get is the package name like "com.katana.facebook" . what i need is the label of the application like facebook

Comment: you mean getLabel name

Comment: yes , label name of the top activity on the stack

Comment: can label name and class name is same ?

Comment: no , when i used the class name it returns "com.katana.facebook.LoginActivity" , i want the app name or label name

Comment: but it can be possible that name like com.facebook.loginactivity,what is your actual need to get application name so that i will suggest according to that

Comment: i am working on  a view that comes over all the applications running on your device (except facebook and whatsapp) , so i want to detect that if the label name of the top activuity matches with (facebook) , i want my view to get invisible

Comment: Scenario: like when on boot reciever is called , i will check the top running activity on the stack . if the lable name of top activity matches with the facebook , i will make my view as invisible

Comment: Means you do have String to compare with application name

Comment: yes i have an applist on which i want my view to get invisible.. i just want to check if the label name of top activity matches with the app list then my condition will be called

Comment: Hi , following code worked for me  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    RunningAppProcessInfo info = am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0);
    try
    {
     CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
     System.out.println("the label of the app is " + c);
     Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     //Name Not FOund Exception
    }

Comment: put it in answer so that every body can know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getTopActivityStackName()
    {
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)
                getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        PackageManager mPackageManager = getPackageManager();
        String packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        ApplicationInfo mApplicationInfo;
        try 
        {
            mApplicationInfo = mPackageManager.getApplicationInfo( packageName, 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            mApplicationInfo = null;
        }
       String appName = (String) (mApplicationInfo != null ? 
               mPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(mApplicationInfo) : "(unknown)");

        return appName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i dont know whether it help you or not ,

```
     PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  RunningAppProcessInfo info = am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0);
 try { 
     CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName,     PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)); System.out.println("the label of the app is " + c); Log.w("LABEL", c.toString()); 
}
 catch(Exception e) { //Name Not FOund Exception 

}
```

Comment: suppose i want to hide my view for the app name X , and the package name of the app X is com.Y.test , then if case wont work